# Tan of sum using differential equations

Tags: abstract-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, exponential-function

Define $S(x)$ and $C(x)$ as exponential functions, and $T(x) = S(x)/C(x)$. We want to derive the formula for $T(x+y)$, but the exercise I'm working on suggests setting up a differential equation $g(T(x)) = T'(x)$.

How is that supposed to help me? I can just derive the formula from exponents, but I don't see any connection between the derivative and the sum formula. In the best case, I can say something about some limit when $y$ goes to 0?

Any help will be appreciated. Maybe there's another question doing a similar thing, I couldn't find anything. This proof approach seems like a popular one and worth knowing. Thank you!

Comment: You are using the definitions $S(x) = \frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}, C(x) = \frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$?

Comment: yes i do @gst076923